# Redondear y truncar SQL + datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hola tengo una tabla de SQL Server 2014 que tiene 2 columnas: Decimales tipo int, Valor tipo decimal, de esta tabla hago una consulta con un SP que luego cargo en un data gridview de C# en un Windows form, el objetivo es que con el valor de la columna Decimales Se realice un redondeo y truncamiento dependiendo de su valor y este valor ya redondeado aparezca en el datagridview de esta forma:

Valores en tabla

```
Decimales         Valores
      3             1.3267
      2             2.43567
```

Valores obtenidos en el data grid View :

```
Decimales            Valor
 3                     1.327
 2                     2.44
```

Hasta ahora he intentado redondear con round en el SP pero no admite el valor de otra Columna como parámetro para la función.

Ojalá puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se resolvió utilizando la función STR de SQL en la cual puedo colocar como longitud el valor de la columna multiparametrico, me da como resultado una string pero no me afecta ya que no hago operaciones numéricas en este caso.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función ROUND, que recibe como parámetros el valor a redondear, y como segundo parámetros los decimales a redondear. Entonces el truco está en usar las columnas como los parámetros de la función.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE #tabla
(
    Decimales int,
    Valores decimal(10,5)
)

INSERT INTO #tabla ([Decimales], [Valores]) values (3, 1.3267)
INSERT INTO #tabla ([Decimales], [Valores]) values (2, 2.43567)

select ROUND(Valores, Decimales), * from #tabla

drop table #tabla
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, mira lo intente de esa forma en SQL 2014 pero me marca error en la consulta, en cuanto esté en la computadora cargo una imagen de la consulta como la tengo, pero me marcó error, he estado pensando en primero dentro de SQL pasarle el valor de la columna a una variable y después utilizarla como el valor de la función aún no sé exactamente cómo.

Comment: El script que te pasé falló, o fue tu tabla la que no está funcionando?

Comment: Lo intente con la mía, en cuanto esté en mi computadora coloco exactamente la consulta que uso.

Comment: Ya funcionó con el ejemplo ahora voy a aplicarlo directo en la consulta problema del programa en producción y en cuanto lo pruebe te comento, de verdad gracias por tu ayuda cuando eres nuevo todo se complica y no ves salida al parecer ya tengo opciones.

Comment: Hola disculpa la tardanza pero ya pude probar en la base de trabajo y si redondea pero al final aparecen los ceros que completan la construcción del tipo de dato, por ejemplo si redondeo 1.43625 a 2 Decimales y el dato es decimal (16,8) me aparece 1.44000000 y necesito que solo aparezca 1.44 sin los ceros, ya intente con truncate pero no me permite utilizar la columna decimal como parámetro de la función.

Comment: Ya intente con CAST y CONVERT y ninguno de los 2 me permite colocar una columna como argumento del largo de la conversión a tipo decimal, es decir como:                                                                                                        CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,[Decimales]),[Valores])    Me marca rror de que no puede ser el valor y que espera un int.                                                           También con CAST me dice que no acepta valores multiparametricos.

Comment: Otro punto importante es que si:                                                         Valor= 1.00043    Y         Decimales= 2       El resultado debe ser     Valor= 1.00 es decir debe mostrar los dos ceros a la izquierda del valor redondeado.

Comment: Lo resolví de la siguiente manera debido a que las funciones de convert, concatenar y cast no admiten valores multiparametricos es decir valores de una columna:                                                                          
                                        
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715101/format-the-number-of-decimals-based-on-another-column-sql